# Use of JSF view parameter through datatables? Possible?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, primefaces, openfaces

Environment: ***JSF 2.0 / JPA (provided by EclipseLink) / Glassfish 3.1 / java-EE-5 /***

- *A small JSF (No Spring, no EJB, no CDI) web application consists mainly on displaying datatables for entities, but the purpose is to display the list of an entity iems for a given Writer:*
- A datatable (`<h:datatable/>`) displays the list of Writers.
- A datatable (`<h:datatable/>`) displays the list of Books written by Writers. (1--*)
- A datatable (`<h:datatable/>`) displays the list of Evaluations given to Writers. (1--*)
- A datatable (`<h:datatable/>`) displays the list of Topics treated by Writers. (1--*).

**This is how I am seeing things:**

Since all the datatables have a column with the Writer ID (primary key of Writer).
How can I achieve telling the current user session to hold a parameter (Writer ID), when the user selects a given writer (preferably from the Writer datatable) and use it to display only the records related to that selected writer row.

The same way, when a user is done with the selected writer, he/she can reset the session to hold another writer ID and explore happily with the new selected writer child items.

In other words, using `<h:datatables />`, and `<f:param />` (or something similar), how can I list Book, Evaluation and Topic items for a selected writer persistently.

*E.G: Persistently for me means = When the user selects a writer from the datatable, and navigates to `/book/List.xhtml` page, the book datatable must list only the book items that the selected writer has. And if the user navigates to somewhere else, he can see only what's related to the same writer.*

One idea is to use OpenFaces datatable filters, but it is too cruel for the end user to filter the table each time he/she navigates to a page. He has to do it only once. 
(An exciting solution is to add an **OpenFaces** filter (`<o:inputTextFilter />`) for each datatable (`<o:datatable >` in that case) and then all the filters for all tables get automatically the writer ID held as parameter by the user session during the JSF cycle. But is that really feasible :( ?

Sorry for the redundancy. Hope someone could help with hints, ideas, solutions or better alternative.
regards.

Comment: Is your target runtime really Java EE 5? Glassfish 3 is a Java EE 6 container. What Servlet version is your `web.xml` declared? GF 3 supports Servlet 3.0 and inherently also EL 2.2 which should make passing arguments easier.

Comment: Any comments? I can post a Java EE 5 targeted answer, but since things can be done more elegantly in Java EE 6, I'd prefer not to waste my time in answering a Java EE 5 solution while you're after all *actually* using Java EE 6. By the way, the same story also applies on your previous question where I left a comment, but never got feedback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358188/jsf-datamodel-jpa-parent-to-leaves-navigation-how-to

Comment: @BalusC I am using Glassfish 3.1 and Java EE5 and JDK 1.6. Actually it seems my EL version is 2.2 as I am able to use parametrized methods and other new features of EL 2.2.
Though, in my sun-web.xml Servlet version is 2.5 as well as in the web.xml.

Comment: @BalusC I am really sorry not to feedback quickly as I did not receive any notification of your comments. In the future I will check all my questions by opening them Whenever I am online.

Comment: Comments are notified by global inbox on the left top. If you see a little red bullet with new message number, you have new comments. But I still don't understand one thing. GF 3.1 is a Java EE 6 container. EL 2.2 is part of Servlet 3.0. Servlet 3.0 is part of Java EE 6. Yet you keep saying that you're using Java EE 5. But you seem to be *actually* using Java EE 6.

Comment: @BalusC When I first created the project in my IDE I specified Java-EE-5, however, please check those screenshots: 
https://picasaweb.google.com/114359438853499737434/My_JSF_Web_App

Comment: Ah right. That must be a Netbeans glitch, I guess.

Comment: @BalusC yeah maybe! I guess it is for some portability reasons (The use of a non Java-EE-6 capable container for example). When specifying Java-EE-5 in netbeans and generating some code, it generates java-EE-5 compatible JPA controllers, but when specifying Java-EE-6, it uses EJB 3.1 (facades, CDI, ..etc). But Anyway, I was ordered not to use EJBs and CDI for now, it is somehow stupid but can't help it! Please go ahead BalusC!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're indeed running Java EE 6 and not Java EE 5, you could just pass the currently selected writer as method argument to the bean in a commandlink/button in a datatable and let the other tables depend on that.

Given the following `Writer` entity:

```
public class Writer {

    private String name;
    private List<Book> books;
    private List<Evaluation> evaluations;
    private List<Topic> topics;

    // ...
}
```

and the following managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped // request or session are also okay.
public class Bean {

    private List<Writer> writers; // +getter
    private Writer writer; // +getter +setter

    // ...
}
```

then you can setup your datatables as follows (in a single view):

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{bean.writers}" var="writer">
        <h:column>#{writer.name}</h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:commandButton value="View" action="#{bean.setWriter(writer)}">
                <f:ajax render=":details" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup id="details">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty bean.writer}">
        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.writer.books}" var="book">
            <h:column>#{book.name}</h:column>
            ...
        </h:dataTable>
        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.writer.evaluations}" var="evaluation">
            <h:column>#{evaluation.name}</h:column>
            ...
        </h:dataTable>
        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.writer.topics}" var="topic">
            <h:column>#{topic.name}</h:column>
            ...
        </h:dataTable>
    </ui:fragment>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: oh :) I'll try that tomorrow afterwork and feedback! Thanks a lot.

Comment: the `ui:fragment` does not have the RENDERED attribute. I used the one available in `h:panelGroup`, and I added <h:form tags to encapsulate the data tables. It works like a charm for displaying lists of items related to a writer in one page.

Comment: My issu was to keep the writer ID through the session so all tables depends on it while navigating through pages! I resolved this issue by hacking the JPA query conditionally (Using the writer setter) and along with your solution my problem is resolved! Thanks again BalusC.

Comment: It certainly supports the `rendered` attribute. You're apparently using Netbeans? Ignore that IDE warning/error and run it. As to the session scope, just make the bean `@SessionScoped`.